# making a realtime listener whenever there is addition in database in php/codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I have a code that I've used ajax. I want something making this real-time. My ajax works by getting all the data from the mysql database and everytime i get data, i used a loop which getting all the data one by one.

What i want is:
How can i make it avoid getting it all again by loop, if there are additional in my database it will only get the additional in the database instead of looping again. and getting all the data again and again. ?

Here is my code in ajax:

```
function show_patients(getClinicID) {
  $("#queue").empty();
  $.ajax({
        url: siteurl+"myclinic/get_patients/"+getClinicID,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.length>0) {
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
              $('#queue').append('<div class="col-sm-10">'+'<div class="panel-group">'+'<div class="panel panel-info">'+
                                  '<div class="panel-heading">'+'<h4><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'">'+data[i]['order_num']+' '+data[i]['patient_lname']+', '+data[i]['patient_fname']+' <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down pull-right"></span></a></h4>'+
                                  '</div><!-- panel-heading -->'+'<div id="patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'+'<div class="panel-body">'+'<div class="row">'+
                                  '<div class="col-sm-5">'+'<small>Patient ID: <label id="patientID">'+data[i]['patient_id']+'</label></small>'+''+'<button onclick="checkstatus('+data[i]['patient_id']+');this.disabled=true;" id="btn'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm ">Check me up</button>'+'</div><!-- col-sm-4 -->'+'<div class="col-sm-6">'+
                                  '<div class="img-patient">'+'<div class="patient-pic" style="background-image: url('+data[i]['patient_photo']+')"></div>'+'</div><!-- img-patient -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-6 -->'+'</div><!-- row -->'+
                                  '</div><!-- panel-body -->'+'</div><!-- panel-collapse -->'+'</div><!-- panel -->'+'</div><!-- panel-group -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-10 -->');
            };
          }
          else {
            $('#queue').append('<h4> No Patients in queue </h4>');
          }
        }
  });
}
```

my code works by getting the data again and again, clearing the div using `$("#queue").empty();` preventing it duplicates. I want to do something, if there is already a data, the added data will be get by not firing the loop again and clear the div again and again every data is added.

Comment: When are calling show_patients function ? Are you calling this function in a time interval ?

Comment: i called it every seconds sir. yes sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should append your data instead of clearing div every time. For get all additional data from your database, you need to hold your last patient id in a javascript variable and pass this patient id to server. At server side add a condition for get all data after last patient id. Assuming patient_id is patient id in your database and clinic_id is for clinic id than your query will be like as

```
select * from table where `patient_id` > PassedPatientId and `clinic_id` = ClinicId
```

You can add your all required other information in mysql query. This is only a sample query for describing for getting all new data from mysql database. First time patient_id will be null so add patient_id in condition when it not null.

```
var lastPatientID = null;
function show_patients(getClinicID) {
      $.ajax({
            url: siteurl+"myclinic/get_patients/"+getClinicID+"/"+lastPatientID,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
              if(data.length>0) {
                for(i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
                  lastPatientID = data[i]['patient_id'];
                  $('#queue').append('<div class="col-sm-10">'+'<div class="panel-group">'+'<div class="panel panel-info">'+
                                      '<div class="panel-heading">'+'<h4><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'">'+data[i]['order_num']+' '+data[i]['patient_lname']+', '+data[i]['patient_fname']+' <span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-down pull-right"></span></a></h4>'+
                                      '</div><!-- panel-heading -->'+'<div id="patientinfo'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'+'<div class="panel-body">'+'<div class="row">'+
                                      '<div class="col-sm-5">'+'<small>Patient ID: <label id="patientID">'+data[i]['patient_id']+'</label></small>'+''+'<button onclick="checkstatus('+data[i]['patient_id']+');this.disabled=true;" id="btn'+data[i]['patient_id']+'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm ">Check me up</button>'+'</div><!-- col-sm-4 -->'+'<div class="col-sm-6">'+
                                      '<div class="img-patient">'+'<div class="patient-pic" style="background-image: url('+data[i]['patient_photo']+')"></div>'+'</div><!-- img-patient -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-6 -->'+'</div><!-- row -->'+
                                      '</div><!-- panel-body -->'+'</div><!-- panel-collapse -->'+'</div><!-- panel -->'+'</div><!-- panel-group -->'+'</div><!-- col-sm-10 -->');
                };
              }
              else {

                  $('#queue').append('<h4> No Patients in queue         </h4>');

              }
            }
      });
    }
```

var lastPatientID is javascript variable  which hold last patient render at page and passed to server for get all new patients.

Comment: hello sir what if i want to remove the upper queue then i want to refresh only the top?